# Is there way to visualize Photoshop changes by EXIF?

Tags: photoshop, metadata, reverse-engineering

Photoshop saves the changes made on the photo to its EXIF (or XMP). Is there any chance of visualizing this data?

Example photo and its EXIF data can be found on my webpage:

[example](https://emirhan.xyz/ba787)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE.
I don't understand your question. Do you want to show the EXIF data as you did on the example webpage? If so, how did you make the example webpage? Perhaps you can use the same method to show the EXIF of other photos?

Comment: When editing raw files ACR creates [image].xmp file and stores edit info on that file. If you open same RAW file in ACR it automatically changes settings according to [image].xmp file. I want to achieve same effect.

Comment: Right, so you're looking for a way to interpret the XMP file and apply the changes within that file on your image, just like ACR does?
What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Why can't you use Photoshop or Lightroom for this?

Comment: Im interested in aviation photography, but my post-processing is really weak. Im liked this photo I want to visually see what post processing done on photo and basically learn from it.

Comment: This seems like you're asking about something unrelated to your real problem. If you're trying to understand another shooter's post processing...you're not going to have access to their XMP file. You need to learn more about post to spot changes and/or ask about individual images on sites like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found site called [Pixelpeeper](https://pixelpeeper.io) which visualizes exactly how I want.

Upon research with site name I found [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightfinder/cifbgbbgjlehgddmhdognpncdjpiepgn) which is more usable and not behind paywall.

Answer (score 0):

My image viewer show this as part of the XMP metadata, so any decent photo viewer should be able to display this:

[image]